# Hose for bleeder valve on baseboard heater

Tags: heater, baseboard

Is there an hose attachment I can buy to help bleed a single baseboard heater valve?

Comment: At my first house my method used a piece of 2” pvc conduit and a bucket. The valves did have threads but most also had been painted.  I just did what worked easily.

Comment: If we have pictures, it would help.